# Double JOIN to get two different parameters?

Tags: mysql

Consider 2 tables: `USERS` and `TASKS` for a task delivery app

```
USERS
userID | email | name

TASKS
userID | designator_userUNIQUE | destination_userUNIQUE
```

To get the `destination_user` full name from the `users` table I am using the following query that works fine:

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM tasks 
 INNER JOIN users ON users.userID = tasks.destination_userUNIQUE
      WHERE tasks.client='$clientUNIQUE' 
   ORDER BY tasks.date DESC, tasks.time DESC
```

However, if I want to get the full name from the `designator_userUNIQUE` using the below query, it simply generates an sql error (`mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource`).

```
     SELECT * 
       FROM tasks
 INNER JOIN users ON users.userID = tasks.destination_userUNIQUE
 INNER JOIN users ON users.name = tasks.designator_user UNIQUE
      WHERE tasks.client='$clientUNIQUE' 
   ORDER BY tasks.date DESC, tasks.time DESC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to alias one of the `users` in the FROM clause, e.g. `INNER JOIN users AS users2` if you actually want to join twice, but it looks like you want to join on multiple conditions instead, in which case you join once using a composite join condition, e.g. `INNER JOIN users ON users.userID = tasks.destination_userUNIQUE AND users.name = tasks.designator_user`.

Comment: Error is gone, but no result is shown

Comment: _"mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource"_ is not a MySQL error; it is a PHP error. Get rid of your PHP from the question and tell us — and, crucially, _yourself_ — the MySQL Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give different aliases to each instance of the `users` table that you join with, to prevent ambiguity.

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN users AS dest ON dest.userID = t.destination_userUNIQUE
INNER JOIN users AS desig ON desig.userID = t.designator_userUNIQUE
WHERE t.client='$clientUNIQUE' 
ORDER BY t.date DESC, t.time DESC
```